# Cannot recognize this type of font

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, computer-modern

I am trying to recognize the font of this document

[Nesmith, Travis D. "Solving Stochastic Money-in-the-utility-function Models." (2005).](https://www.federalreserve.gov/pubs/feds/2005/200552/200552pap.pdf)

It seems to belong in the modern family, but it is not identical with the default computer modern font.

Answer (score 1):

Edited after OP's clarification.

For example, the inner names are:

1. The word `Abstract` is of the family TTdcbx10.
2. Then `This paper analyzes` is of the family TTdcr10

https://en.fontke.com/font/23640064/

Comment: I am referring to the font of the main text (not the cover). I have seen this type of font in many working papers, and I assume that it is quite known.

Comment: @AlexandrosB  Is the changed version valuable to you?